# String to datetime django

Tags: python, django

I have this string:

```
2014-03-13T15:10:07Z
```

And I need convert it to 'value', that I can save in **Django DateTimeField**. I know, how to do this without `T` and `Z`:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_object = datetime.strptime('2014-03-13 15:10:07', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Does I need to delete `T` and `Z` from string? Will it saves in DateTimeField?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you add T and Z to the format you give you strptime?

Comment: I add and all works. Does it saves in DateTimeField?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to parse a datetime string is with [`dateutil.parser.parse()`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) from the third-party [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) module:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2014-03-13T15:10:07Z')
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 13, 15, 10, 7, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

This returns a [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) instance which will be *aware* of the timezone if it is present in the string (i.e., ending with `Z`, `-04:00`, etc.).